# Main activity not starting

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two activities in my program one where you type something into a text field then click a button to send it to another where it is displayed. Though, the one where it is being displayed shows up first. 
It may be that they start at the same time, I'm not sure.
My main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

   public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "   com.mycompany.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    startActivity(new Intent(getApplication(), second.class));
    }
    public void sendMessage(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, second.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
    // Do something in response to button
    }
```

The xml file that goes with

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

      <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:onClick="sendMessage" />

      <EditText

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My android manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".second"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_second"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
      <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.mycompany.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

My second .java file

```
public class second extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    // Set the text view as the activity layout
    setContentView(textView);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you're going to invoke the second.class with an intent, you're going to need an intent-filter marked inside the activity of the manifest. This is similar to that of the first class.

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

So your android manifest should look something like this:

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".second"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_second"
    android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
  <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>
  <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.mycompany.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

Learn more about the [Intents here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your line:

```
startActivity(new Intent(getApplication(), second.class));
```

starts the second activity as soon as the first one starts.

Remove this line as you are already doing what you need to in your sendMessage().

Comment: Typically people will accept an answer (the checkmark on the left) if it solves their problem. Here is a [tour](/tour) with some nice info.